# Invalid fragment shader. Link cannot proceed

Tags: java, android, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

At the beginning of my project, I used simple `String`s for filling my both `Shader`s with code. This looked like this:

```
    public final static String chunkDefaultVertexInit = ""
    +constantParameters
    +"precision mediump float;"

    +"uniform mat4 mPMatrix;"
    +"uniform mat4 mVMatrix;"
    +"uniform mat4 mMMatrix;"
    +"uniform mat4 mMVMatrix;"

    +"attribute vec4 Vertex;"
    +"attribute vec3 Normal;"
    +"attribute vec2 TexCoord;"

    +"varying vec3 normal;"
    +"varying vec2 uv;"
    +"varying vec4 positionM;"
    +"varying vec4 positionMV;";
    etc....
```

This worked for me, but it was not really clearly. So I thought about how I could make my code a little bit more clean and clearly for everybody. My idea was, to put my whole bunch of code in a real `.cc` - file and move it into the res/raw folder. No sooner said than done.
I wanted to read out my code via Inputstreams and save it into a String. That also worked fine, and so I fed the shader the String source.

So... now there happend to be a problem, and as I said, I didn't get it yet. I even made me a little bit angry about myself, because I thought about an easy way of fix it and I don't see it.

I even did show my source code I put in... but it looks correct! o.O

```
Log.i("Llama3D Shader",shaderCode);
```

(Don't worry about the weird "Debug ID," it's the projects name)

Here's the source code for the shaders:

**Vertexshader:**

```
//vertexshader
precision mediump float;

uniform mat4 mPMatrix;
uniform mat4 mVMatrix;
uniform mat4 mMMatrix;
uniform mat4 mMVMatrix;

attribute vec4 aVertex;
attribute vec3 aNormal;
attribute vec2 aTexCoord;

varying vec2 vecTexCoord;
varying vec3 vecNormal;
varying vec4 vecVertex[2];

void main() {
    gl_Position = mPMatrix * mMVMatrix * aVertex;
    vecVertex[0] = mMMatrix * aVertex;
    vecVertex[1] = mMVMatrix * aVertex;
    vecTexCoord = aTexCoord;
    vecNormal = normalize(vec3(mMMatrix * -vec4(aNormal,0.0)));
}
```

**Fragmentshader:**

```
#define MAX_POINT_LIGHTS 4
precision mediump float;

varying vec2 vecTexCoord;
varying vec3 vecNormal;
varying vec4 vecVertex[2];

uniform vec3 uVecEye;
uniform vec3 uPointLightPosition[MAX_POINT_LIGHTS];
uniform vec3 uPointLightColor[MAX_POINT_LIGHTS];
uniform sampler2D textureHandle;

vec3 V = normalize(uVecEye.xyz-vecVertex[1].xyz);
vec3 N = vNormal;

vec3 vecLight[MAX_POINT_LIGHTS];
vec4 pointDiffuse  = vec4(0.0);
vec4 pointSpecular = vec4(0.0);

vec4 ambient = vec4(0.2,0.2,0.2,1.0);
vec4 color = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
vec4 matSpec = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
vec4 lightSpec = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
vec4 spec = matSpec * lightSpec;

float shininess = 20.0;

void main() {
    for (int i=0;i<MAX_POINT_LIGHTS;i++) {

        vecLight[i].xyz = vecVertex[0].xyz - uPointLightPosition[i].xyz;
        float vecDistance = length(vecLight[i].xyz);

        if (vecDistance<=25.0) {

            vecDistance = 1.0 - max(0.0,vecDistance)/25.0;
            vec3 L = normalize(vecLight[i]);
            vec3 R = normalize(reflect(L,N));
            float LND = max(0.0,dot(N,L)) * vecDistance;

            pointDiffuse += color * vec4(uPointLightColor[i].xyz,0.0) * LND;

            if (shininess!=0.0 && spec!=0.0) {
                pointSpecular += spec * pow(max(0.0,dot(R,V)),shininess) * LND;
            } else {
                pointSpecular += vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
            }
        }
    }
    vec4 colorTexture = texture2D(textureHandle,vec2(+vTexCoord.x,-vTexCoord.y));
    gl_FragColor = ambient + colorTexture * pointDiffuse + pointSpecular;
}
```

Every time I try to run the program, the ShaderlogInfo and ProgramlogInfo say to me:

> Invalid fragment shader. Link cannot proceed.*

Am I crazy or just blind?!
I hope you know an answer... I really don't know any... please help me!

Comment: What do the compilation and linking logs say?

Comment: How do I get these compilation and linking logs in eclipse? Obviously I don't see them yet :/

Comment: That's not Eclipse's responsibility. Shader compile/link errors are something _you_ have to check for in your code. They're part of the runtime compilation of shaders. You have to get them with your code and display them if there are compiler/linker errors. I don't know how Android and Java handle it, but [this page](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLSL#Error_Checking) explains how to do it in C/C++ code.

Comment: Yeah okay, I did that actually o.O But the log doesn't say anything else. It still says: invalid fragment shader. Link cannot proceed. Not more or less... It even says that, when I reduce my Fragmentshader to varyings and one "gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);" command. Might the problem be one of the varyings?

Comment: What you said is not possible. The *shader* infolog most certainly did not say "Link cannot proceed", because shaders don't do *linking*. So what did the *shader* infolog say for the fragment shader? Post your log printing code, please.

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13497625/Android/DebugGLSL.png Here's a screenshot of Debuglog ... it doesn't say anything else. :( Am I looking at the right place?! Perhaps the log you want to see is anywhere else?

Comment: I'm not an Android developer. I don't know what kind of special settings and whatnot you're using in your build environment. Maybe you have some stand-alone compiler and are going to load shader binaries at runtime. I don't know where that error message comes from or what tool created it. All I know is how you generally get errors in desktop OpenGL.

Comment: Okay... oh. Yeah thanks so much anyways! I will keep on finding the problem and post the solution ;)

Comment: Hit me with a fist of zen... I changed vTexCoord into vecTexCoord.... I saw the failure, when I rebuilt the shader step by step. Now it works! thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The log you got is from the Program linking stage, glGetProgramInfoLog.

What you need to debug is the Fragment Shader log, glGetShaderInfoLog.

Something along these lines:

```
def _compile(self, source):
    ptr = cast(c_char_p(source), POINTER(c_char))
    glShaderSource(self.id, 1, byref(ptr), None)
    glCompileShader(self.id)
    status = c_int(0)
    glGetShaderiv(self.id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, byref(status))
    log = self.check()
    print(log),
    if not status.value:
        raise Exception(log)

def check(self):
    length = c_int(0)
    glGetShaderiv(self.id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, byref(length))
    log = create_string_buffer(length.value)
    glGetShaderInfoLog(self.id, length.value, None, log)
    return log.value
```

Though this is not in java but in python, it should give you an idea of how to get your shader compile log.

Compiling your shaders in my environment gives me this log which may or may not be useful to you:

```
Vertex shader was successfully compiled to run on hardware.
WARNING: 0:2: warning(#260) Keyword 'precision' is supported in GLSL 1.3 
Fragment shader failed to compile with the following errors:
WARNING: 0:2: warning(#260) Keyword 'precision' is supported in GLSL 1.3
ERROR: 0:14: error(#143) Undeclared identifier vNormal
WARNING: 0:14: warning(#402) Implicit truncation of vector from size 1 to size 3. 
ERROR: 0:50: error(#143) Undeclared identifier vTexCoord
ERROR: 0:50: error(#216) Vector field selection out of range 'y'
ERROR: error(#273) 4 compilation errors.  No code generated
```

Comment: wish i could @Berserker but i didn't ask the question :)